Powershell - XML rename node name based upon child node value
I need to rename the name of a parent node based upon the value of a child node.
So far, this is what I have:
$path = 'C:\temp\test.xml'
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $path)

$paramnode = $xml.SelectNodes('//outbound')

foreach($node in $paramnode){
    if($node.InnerText -eq '0'){
        $node.ParentNode.Name = 'outbound'
    }else{
        $node.ParentNode.Name = 'inbound'
    }

Unfortunately, the Name property looks to be read-only.   Any ideas?

You can't.  I usually create new node and then copy child nodes from original.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

You'd need to provide a sample of your XML however using a simple example, basically what you can do is replace the selected node with a new one having the desired name:
$xml = [xml] '<foo><bar>hello</bar></foo>'
# get the node to replace
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//bar')
# create a new one with the desired name
$newchild = $xml.CreateElement('baz')
$newchild.InnerText = 'hello'
# replace the node with the new one
$null = $node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($newchild, $node)
$xml.InnerXml # => <foo><baz>hello</baz></foo>


This seems to be targeting the child element.  I need to use a child element to target parent elements.  There will be a whole lot of parent elements with the same name, and they all need renamed.  So,  becomes  or , based upon whether  has value 0 or 1.
